# Programmatically changing the properties of a VC's navigation bar button in response to a button press in another VC

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uinavigationbar

I've created a navigation bar button in `MainViewController` using

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()    

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(presentPopup))
        
}
    
@objc func presentPopup() {
        
    let popupVC = PopupViewController()
    popupVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    present(popupVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
}
```

which presents a popup form (containing a "save" button) used for saving the main view's contents. I'd like for this "save" button (in `PopupViewController`) to (1) change the title of `MainViewController`'s navigation bar button to "Saved" and (2) disable the button.

I have the following in `PopupViewController` so far:

```swift
let popupBox: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

let button: UIButton = {
    let view = UIButton()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
    view.backgroundColor = .clear
        
    view.addSubview(popupBox)
    // configure popupBox

    view.addSubview(button)
    // configure button
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        
}

@objc func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // save main VC's contents
    // change title of main VC's nav button - WHAT GOES HERE?
    // disable main VC's nav button - WHAT GOES HERE?
    self.dismiss(animated: true)  // dismiss popup
    
}
```

What should I add to the button's action to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a callback to `PopupViewController`, that will be called in `buttonAction`.

```
var onDismiss: (() -> Void)?

@objc func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    dismiss(animated: true)
    onDismiss?()
    //or,  you can also run onDismiss after the dismiss animation:
    // dismiss(animated: true, completion: onDismiss)
}
```

Assign the thing you want to do before presenting the popup:

```
@objc func presentPopup() {
    let popupVC = PopupViewController()
    popupVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    popupVC.onDismiss = { [weak self] in
        guard let self else { return }
        self.navigationItem.title = "Saved"
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
    }
    present(popupVC, animated: true, completion: nil)       
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Sweeper! This is almost what I was looking for. Since I want to change the title of the nav bar's right bar button, the penultimate line of `onDismiss` should be `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title = "Saved"`. Works like a charm!

Comment: @vonbecker I see. I misunderstood which "title" you wanted to change.